# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range al utilizar substring

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al usar la función substring en java. Lo que quiero hacer es más que nada reducir el tamaño de longitud de una cadena. Este es mi código:

```
public static boolean generaReporte(List<LayoutCPBES> lstReporte, String ruta, String nombreReporte) {
    boolean resultado = false;
    FileWriter writer;
    String nuevaLinea ="";
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(ruta + nombreReporte);
        String folio ="";
        for (LayoutCPBES lstPagos : lstReporte) {
                        
            nuevaLinea = lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura() + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaNacional()+"|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaConsolidada() + "|" + lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaIndividual()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCorte() + "|"+ lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRegion()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumTelefono()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUuidRelacionado()+"|"+ lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumParcialidad() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSeqNumFineq()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoAnterior()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImporte() + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto()
                    //nuevos campos jj                              
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTasa()                     
                    
                    //Campos donde viene TASA(descripcion en el archivo, puede o no venir TASA)
                    //+ "|" +""
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDescTasa()
                    
                    
                    
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getExento()
                    //CAMPO DONDE VIENE EXENTO (descripcion en el archivo, puede o no venir EXENTO)
                    +"|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDescExento()
                    //nuevos campos jj
                    
                    
                    + "|" + lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaPago()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSerie()
                    + "|" +     lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFolio() 
                    + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImeiSacPhone() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImeiFineq() + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago() + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getMetodoPagoM2k()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNombreCliente()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRfcReceptor()
                    //Nuevos campos jj
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal()

                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCodPostal()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getClaveRegFiscal()
                    //nuevos campos jj
                    
                    + "|"+  lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getOrigenPago() + "|"+lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUsuarioPago()+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getAcctId()
                    + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getEstatusPago() + "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCreacionBES();
            lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setLayoutPago(nuevaLinea);
            writer.write(lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getLayoutPago() + System.lineSeparator());
            //LOG.info("fOLIO SIN LOS 0" + lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFolio());
        }
        writer.close();
        resultado = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("[TBVRB] Ocurrio una excepción al generar el reporte" + nombreReporte, e);
        resultado = false;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Donde se necesita reducir a solo 115 caracteres es en el domicilio fiscal que sería en esta parte donde estoy concatenando:

```
+ "|" +lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal()
```

Intenté poner al final `.substring(0, 115)` pero me marca error de:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 115

¿Hay alguna manera de realizar esta adecuación?

Como ejemplo pondría una cadena:

```
ACCESO A PRADERAS DE SAN MATEO 41EDIFICIO MAKENZI704 LOMAS VERDES (CONJUNTO LOMAS VERDES) NAUCALPAN DE JUAREZ MEXICO
```

y como se desea es que solo queden 115 caracteres

```
ACCESO A PRADERAS DE SAN MATEO 41EDIFICIO MAKENZI704 LOMAS VERDES (CONJUNTO LOMAS VERDES) NAUCALPAN DE JUAREZ MEXIC
```

y así con más cadenas que superen los 115 caracteres.

Comment: ¿De qué línea viene el error? ¿Estás seguro de que la cadena tiene 116 caracteres o más? ¿Con qué cadena está ejecutando la función?

Comment: Lo que pasa es estoy leyendo un archivo de texto y ese archivo lee toda una cadena pero yo especificamente quiero manipular lo que tiene getDomFiscal si por ejemplo tiene mas de 115 caracteres, solo necesitaría los primeros 115 ya que en la bd a donde los quiero insertar solo está limitada a 115

Comment: y todas los domicilios fiscales de tu archivo de texto son mayores a 115 caracteres?, la excepción te dice este error ocurre cuando se intenta acceder a un índice en una cadena que está fuera de su rango, es decir parece que tienes un domicilio fiscal o varios menores a 115

Comment: Exactamente, entonces para solo traer los primeros 115 como lo podría hacer? pense que solo usando el substring y poniendo el inicio y final (la posicion que quiero solamente) funcionaría

Comment: Por ejemplo, "ACCESO A PRADERAS DE SAN MATEO 41EDIFICIO MAKENZI704 LOMAS VERDES (CONJUNTO LOMAS VERDES) NAUCALPAN DE JUAREZ MEXICO
" este es el mas largo y pueden que existan mas y como mencionaste, hay domicilios mas chicos que este ejemplo

Comment: entonces debes validar que solo a las direcciones mayores a 115 se les aplique subString(0,115)

Comment: Ya metí la validacion y si entra pero por alguna razón no lo recorta, esta es m validación:   if(lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal().length()>=116) {
    
     lstPagos.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getDomFiscal().substring(0, 115);
     
    }

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás teniendo, es que si tratás de hacer un [string.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) con un valor de última posición, mayor a la longitud del `String`, se va a interrumpir la ejecución del método lanzando la exception [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). En la misma documentación lo dice lo aclara

> Throws:
>
> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the beginIndex is negative, or
> endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or
> beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Lo que está indicando es que tanto si el parámetro `beginIndex` es negativo, o `endIndex` es mayor a la longitud de la cadena, será lanzada dicha exception.

La forma de solucionarlo  no es única. En el artículo [Cómo acortar una cadena de caracteres de Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-truncating-strings) explica varias formas. Pido disculpas por no poder poner links en castellano, pero se dificulta a veces encontrarlos. Dejo algunos ejemplos que el mismo artículo comenta al respecto

- Usar substring en conjunto con un if para validar la longitud de la cadena

```java
String text = obtenerUnTextoAleatorio();
int longitudMaxima = 115;

if (text.length() <= longitudMaxima) {
    return text;
} else {
    return text.substring(0, longitudMaxima);
}
```

- usar método split en combinación con expresiones regulares

```java
String[] results = text.split("(?<=\\G.{" + length + "})");
return results[0];
```

- uso del método `codePoints` de la clase `CharSequence`

```java
text.codePoints()
  .limit(length)
  .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
  .toString();
```

como puedes ver hay muchas formas. Cada una tiene sus pros y cons. Según el caso que tengas que resolver y otros factores más, pueden serte de utilidad más una u otra.